# Zero posts returned with get_posts() on edit.php, but posts are returned on post.php

Tags: get-posts

I have a function which returns all posts of a certain post type, simplified here:

```
public static function getFoos()
{
    $output = array();

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => Foo::POST_TYPE,
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $output[$post->ID] = $post->post_title;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

When I call this function from within the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook on `post.php`, I correctly get the three posts expected. However, when this function is run from within the same hook on `edit.php` zero posts are returned. It can be seen that the `getFoos()` function does not accept any parameters.

I notice that on `post.php` requests the `class-wp-query->get_posts()` function produces this SQL:

```
SELECT   alt_posts.* FROM alt_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND alt_posts.post_type = 'foo' AND ((alt_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY alt_posts.post_date DESC \G
```

However on `edit.php` requests it produces this SQL:

```
SELECT   alt_posts.* FROM alt_posts  LEFT JOIN alt_term_relationships ON (alt_posts.ID = alt_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
alt_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (69)
) AND alt_posts.post_type = 'foo' AND ((alt_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY alt_posts.ID ORDER BY alt_posts.post_date DESC
```

**Why isn't `get_posts()` returning the same output on different calls?**

Comment: It seems that in your second case a filter on a taxonomy term is applied. Please note that get_posts is affected by functions attached to the pre_get_posts hook even if suppress_filters is enabled.

Comment: Thank you, there are hundreds of lines for me to debug in the SQL-generation code, but you've given me a good direction to start in.

Comment: Dont use $post - give this variable a different name.